# print all prefixes of a string - translate from python to bash

Tags: python, bash

I have a shell script that needs to take an `.so` and get all its prefixes, where a prefix is the part of the name, up until the `".so"` part + the next part up until the `"."`.

Example: for `'example.so.1'` we'll have the following prefixes: `'example.so', 'example.so.1'`

I have a python(3) code that does it, and I want to get a bash equivalent.

---

Bash wrapper for the Python source:

```
#!/bin/bash


dst='/tmp'
for src in 'example.so' 'example.so.1' 'example.so.1.2' 'example.so.1.2.3'; do
python3 -c "
import os, sys, itertools as it, re;
so_path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]);
dst = sys.argv[2];
so = os.path.basename(so_path);
so_name = so.split('.')[0];
regex = '\.\w+';
for suffix in it.accumulate(re.findall(regex, so)):
    dst_so = os.path.join(dst, so_name + suffix)
    print('src: {}. dst: {}'.format(so_path, dst_so))
" "${src}" "${dst}";
done
```

---

This is my tryout in bash using awk (it's not complete and only prints the source. I keep tweaking it, but can't get it do exactly what I want):

```
#!/bin/bash

dst='/tmp'
delimiter='.'
for src in 'example.so' 'example.so.1' 'example.so.1.2' 'example.so.1.2.3'; do
    for nubmer_of_delimiters in `seq $(echo ${src} | grep ${delimiter} | wc -l)`; do
        echo ${src} :: ${src} | awk -F. '{print $nubmer_of_delimiters}';
    done
done
```

---

What would be the best way to achieve this? (I'm guessing `awk`, though I did try to use a bit og `cut, sed, etc.`

*The bash code must run on clean ubuntu18 with no extra installs*

Comment: Do it in `awk`. It will like 1:1  with awk.

Comment: @ClsForCookies : Have a look at `basename`. For instance, `basename example.so.1` writes _example_ to stdout. If you need more flexibility, look at the bash man-page to the section titles _Parameter Expansion_, in particular the _Remove matching suffix pattern_ part.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like [this](https://ideone.com/BrorMk), I tried to make it as hard to understand as your question.

Comment: @oguzismail much appreciated :) Can you point out what was problematic in my question, so I'll know how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be able to just shave in a loop.
given `f=example.so.1.2.3`, try

```
$: while [[ "$f" =~ [.]so[.] ]]; do echo "$f"; f=${f%.*}; done; echo "$f"
example.so.1.2.3
example.so.1.2
example.so.1
example.so
```

If you want the smaller ones first, pass it through a sort.

```
$: { while [[ "$f" =~ [.]so[.] ]]
>    do echo "$f"
>       f=${f%.*}
>    done
>    echo "$f"
>  } | sort
example.so
example.so.1
example.so.1.2
example.so.1.2.3
```